# Login sequence using DataSet in Windows Form (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a `DataSet` for my users tables called `UserDataSet` and added a `SELECT` query which filters by username and password called `GetDataByAuthentication(Username,Password)`

Now, I'm trying to retrieve the row's columns returned when I call `UsersTableAdapter.GetDataByAuthentication` but I can't figured out how. Here's my code:

```
Dim table As UsersDataSet.UsersDataTable = Me.TableAdapter.GetDataByAuthentication(_User.Username, _User.Password)

    If (table.Rows.Count > 0) Then

        Dim row as DataRow = table.Rows(0)

        _User.FirstName = // what here?
        _User.LastName = // what here?
        _User.Username = // what here?
        _User.Password = // what here?
        _User.IsAdmin = // what here?

        Return True
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess...

Replace row definition for:

```
Dim row as UsersDataSet.UsersRow
```

and then:

```
_User.FirstName = row.FirstName ' Or whatever is the FirstName column.
```

and `row` will have the properties you're looking for...

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be `UsersDataSet.UsersDataRow` but this is essentially correct.

Comment: @ConradFrix I promise you I thought the same, and before put the answer opened Visual Studio to ensure the right value here :) ... Table names are [TABLE]DataTable and rows are [TABLE]Row. Thank you for the advice!